# Custom non REST method in Backbone collection

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

This is my Backbone collection:

```
var TodoList = Backbone.Collection.extend({

        // Reference to this collection's model.
        model: Todo,

        url: function () {
            return 'api/todos';
        },

        // Filter down the list of all todo items that are finished.
        done: function () {
            return this.filter(function (todo) { return todo.get('done'); });
        },

        // Filter down the list to only todo items that are still not finished.
        remaining: function () {
            return this.without.apply(this, this.done());
        },

        // We keep the Todos in sequential order, despite being saved by unordered
        // GUID in the database. This generates the next order number for new items.
        nextOrder: function () {
            if (!this.length) return 1;
            return this.last().get('order') + 1;
        },

        // Todos are sorted by their original insertion order.
        comparator: function (todo) {
            return todo.get('order');
        },

        addToDo: function (opts) {
            var model = this;
            opts.url = model.url() + '/AddToDo'

            // add any additional options, e.g. a "success" callback or data
            _.extend(options, opts);
            return (this.sync || Backbone.sync).call(this, null, this, options);
        }

    });
```

This works fine and I can hit my URL endpoint. However, the issue is with the built in `create` defined in Backbone collection, the model gets automatically added to the collection once create is called. With my custom method `addToDo` the to-do is added successfully but I can't see it in my view unless I refresh the page.

What am I missing? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.create is syntactic sugar around `model.save` and `collection.add`
If you're model is being created in a different way, you need to override your `sync` method on the **model** to something like:

```
sync: function (method, model, options) {
  options || (options = {});
  if (method === 'create') {
    options.url = _.result(model, 'url') + '/AddToDo';
  }
  return Backbone.Model.prototype.sync.call(this, method, model, options);
}
```